# Show that $(I,J,M)$ are colinear

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let $(ABCD)$ be a non-cyclical, convex quadrilateral, with no parallel sides.
The lines $(AB)$ and $(CD)$ meet in $(E)$. Let $(M \neq E)$ be the intersection of the circumcircles of $(ADE)$ and $(BCE)$.

The internal angle bisectors of $(ABCD)$ form a convex, cyclical quadrilateral with circumcenter $(I)$. The external angle bisectors of $(ABCD)$ form a convex, cyclical quadrilateral with circumcenter $(J)$.

Show that $(I,J,M)$ are colinear.

[image: Diagram]

**Solution:** Let $ W $ be the intersection of the external bisector of $ \angle A, $ $ \angle B $ and define $ X, $ $ Y, $ $ Z $ similarly. Let $ F $ be the intersection of $ AD, $ $ BC $ and let $ \Phi_M $ be the inversion with center $ M, $ power $ MA $ $ \cdot $ $ MC $ $ = $ $ MB $ $ \cdot $ $ MD $ $ = $ $ ME $ $ \cdot $ $ MF $ followed by reflection on the bisector $ \tau $ of $ \angle AMC, $ $ \angle BMD, $ $ \angle EMF. $ Since $ \measuredangle AZE $ $ = $ $ \measuredangle FYC, $ so by conformal $ \Longrightarrow $ $ \Phi_M(Z) $ lies on $ \odot (CFY). $ Similarly, we can prove $ \Phi_M(Z) $ lies on $\odot (BFW), $ so $ \Phi_M(Z) $ is the Miquel point of the complete quadrilateral $ BWYC $ and $ \Phi_M(Z) $ $ \in $ $ \odot (J). $ Similarly, we can prove $ \Phi_M(W), $ $ \Phi_M(X), $ $ \Phi_M(Y) $ lie on $ \odot (J), $ so $ J $ $ \in $ $ \tau. $ Analogously, we can prove $ I $ $ \in $ $ \tau. $

Could someone solve this problem by elementary mathematics, please?

I also don't believe the above "solution" is totally correct.
(Z prime lies on circumscribed circle of CFY)

Comment: Could you add a drawing to clarify and demonstrate the claim?

Comment: @Moti I do not have

Comment: So draw one and present it. Do not expect us to do it for you:)

Comment: @Moti I added the diagram myself ;)

Comment: Which contest is this? It fucking difficult!

Comment: Yeah, sure: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q3h1966618p13619974

Comment: @Tortugut: You should mention that you copied the solution from AOPS (see @ Aqua's comment); ideally, you should link to that solution to give proper credit. Otherwise, people might get the mistaken impression that it's your work. (I realize that you didn't identify it as such.) Also, in situations like this, you might want to say something about what exactly about the given proof bothers you.

Comment: @Blue Of course, it was done!